# Rails API/Pundit: Strong parameters with ActiveModelSerializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api, pundit

[This](https://github.com/varvet/pundit#strong-parameters) section of Pundit section says that we could control which attributes are authorized to be updated. But it fails in case of the use of `active_model_seriallizers` gem:

```
def post_params
  # originally geneated by scaffold
  #params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :user_id)

  #To deserialize with active_model_serializers
  ActiveModelSerializers::Deserialization.jsonapi_parse!(
        params,
        only: [:title, :body, :user]
      )
end
```

If I modify the `PostsController` `update` action as Pundit suggested:

```
def update
  if @post.update(permitted_attributes(@post))
    render jsonapi: @post
  else
    render jsonapi: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

it fails with error:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: post):
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:29:in `update'
```

I also create the `PostPolicy` as follows:

```
class PostPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def permitted_attributes
    if user.admin? || user.national?
      [:title, :body]
    else
      [:body]
    end
  end
end
```

but it has no impact on the above error.

Any idea on how can we do that?

Comment: `ActionController::ParameterMissing` is raised by [`ActionController::Parameters.html#require`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-require) so you may be looking at the wrong culprit.

Comment: I'm getting closer to the solution. I added `pundit_params_for` to the `PostsController` as follows: ```def pundit_params_for(_record)
      params.fetch(:data, {}).fetch(:attributes, {})
    end```, and modified the `update` action as follows: ```def update
    if @post.update(permitted_attributes(@post))
      render jsonapi: @post
    else
      render jsonapi: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end ```. Now if a User is not authorized to update `title`, I see in the console: `Unpermitted parameter: :title`.

Comment: Nice, but I would consider using `require(:data).require(:attributes)` instead of fetch. You want to bail early here as there is no point in continuing if the input does not match the spec.

Comment: did you mean `fail early` instead of `bail early` ?

Comment: Yeah, you say tomato...

Comment: I think, to be able to raise and catch the exception in case of unpermitted parameters, I'll have to add `ActionController::Parameters.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise` somewhere in `application.rb`. Then rescue it in the `application_controller.rb` in a custom way to send back with the response JSON.

Comment: You can just use `rescue_from`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came to (thanks to @max for some tips and tricks) is as follows:

1. Add the following line to `config/application.rb`:

```
config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise
```

2. Add the `rescue_from` either to the `AplicationController` or the one you are precisely interested:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::MimeResponds
  include Pundit

  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, ActionController::UnpermittedParameters, with: :user_not_authorized

...
private

def user_not_authorized
    render jsonapi: errors_response, status: :unathorized
  end

  def errors_response
    {
      errors:
      [
        { message: 'You are not authorized to perform this action.' }
      ]
    }
  end
end
```

Then add `pundit_params_for` method to the `PostsController` and change the `update` action (in my case I'd like to restrict some attributes in `update` action only:)

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
...

def update
  if @post.update(permitted_attributes(@post))
    render jsonapi: @post
  else
    render jsonapi: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end

private
  def post_params
     ActiveModelSerializers::Deserialization.jsonapi_parse!(
       params,
       only: [:title, :body, :user]
     )
    end

  def pundit_params_for(_record)
    params.fetch(:data, {}).fetch(:attributes, {})
  end
end
```

Voilà. Now if an unpermitted attribute will be submitted for the `update` action, the response will have `500` status and contain the error as specified in `ApplicationController#errors_response method`.

**ATTENTION**: It still fails if you have some relations posted with the request (for example, you can have an `Author` as belongs_to relation with `Post`). Using `pundit_params_for` as before will fail to extract the corresponding `author_id` value. To see the way, here my [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59180773/use-pundit-with-strong-parameters-in-rails-api) post where I explained how to use it.

Hope this helps.