# Use Pundit with strong parameters in Rails API

Tags: rails-api, pundit

How is it possible to use Pundit [strong parameters](https://github.com/varvet/pundit#strong-parameters) when working with JSON API if a model contains some relations?
I have already [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58559549/rails-api-pundit-strong-parameters-with-activemodelserializers) a question that explained how to work around with it in case of a single model.
Son here is what works:

```rb
# posts_controller.rb

def update
    if @post.update(permitted_attributes(@post))
      render jsonapi: @post
    else
      render jsonapi: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

private

  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def post_params
    ActiveModelSerializers::Deserialization.jsonapi_parse(
      params,
      only: [:title, :body, :user]
    )
  end

  def pundit_params_for(_record)
    params.fetch(:data, {}).fetch(:attributes, {})
  end
```

Unfortunately it will fail to extact models defined in `relationships` block of the request JSON, foe example:

```
"relationships"=>{"country"=>{"data"=>{"type"=>"countries", "id"=>"1"}}, "language"=>{"data"=>{"type"=>"languages", "id"=>"245"}}}
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to make it work.
The method `pundit_params_for` defined in the `PostsController` should return `ActionController::Parameters` object adn should reuse already extracted data in `post_params` using `ActiveModelSerializers::Deserialization.jsonapi_parse!` method:

```
# posts_controller.rb

private

  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def post_params
    ActiveModelSerializers::Deserialization.jsonapi_parse!(
      params,
      only: [:body, :framework, :title, :user]
    )
  end

  def pundit_params_for(_record)
    ActionController::Parameters.new(post_params)   
  end
```

So I had to pass in `post_params` to `ActionController::Parameters` constructor.
Then in the controller `update` action, you will have to use `permitted_attributes` method as explained in Pundit docs as follows:

```rb
# posts_controller.rb

def update
  if @post.update(permitted_attributes(@post))
    render jsonapi: @post
  else
    render jsonapi: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

As for `create` action, it has nothing special and just follows the docs of Pundit:

```rb
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  authorize @post
  if @post.save
    render jsonapi: @post, status: :created, location: @post
  else
    render jsonapi: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

And here how `PostPolicy` looks like:

```rb
# policies/post_policy.rb

class PostPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def permitted_attributes
    if user.admin?
      [:title, :body, :framework_id, :user_id]
    else
      [:body]
    end
  end

  def create?
    user.admin?
  end
end
```

Hope this helps.